# Original Flash Player script - need to compile .as and .fla to .swf

Tags: flash, compilation, actionscript

I have some old Flash Player script from back in the day that I'd like to revive by using a Flash Player emulator (ruffle). Problem is, the files are in .as and .fla and I can't find anything that can compile them into .swf so that the emulator will work.
Can anyone point me in the right direction (this is all very new to me so I'd need some very clear instructions!) or even tell me if it's possible to do?
Someone tried to open them in Adobe animate on my behalf but they had no success in opening the .fla files. The .as files opened, but displayed just like it would in WordPad/Notebook or something.
It isn't an old recreational game so won't be found on any of those archive sites (it's more of a timed test/quiz that I can use for research; I don't have the resources to have it re-made)

Thanks for your time!

Comment: _"Someone tried to open them in Adobe animate on my behalf but they had no success in opening the .fla files"_ Can you find out if there was an error message? (the details might be useful)... FLA files are specific to the Flash/Animate software so you likely need that part to work to access any graphics/sounds/text etc that the AS code is controlling. PS: What do you mean for research? like learning how the quiz was made?

Comment: I've now had success in exporting the FLA files to SWF using animate but not the AS2 files unfortunately. So I'm still troubleshooting! No error message.
I want it to gather data as part of some research into people's perceptions. It's called an IAT (examples here: https://implicit.harvard.edu/implicit/takeatest.html). I'd use it as part of a wider impact assessment for a work project. Unfortunately, this Flash Player one seems to be the only pre-made test on the topic of interest! Not having the skill or funds for a new one, it would be a shame if we can't bring it back to life.

Comment: I don't think AS2 is supported in Animate. You need an older version like [Flash CS6 (download)](https://archive.org/details/animatearchive_FlashCS6-WIN). That one should compile your AS2 project files into an SWF. I was asking about error because I was afraid you might have AS2 files which would not be supported in Animate hence your _"no success in opening the .fla"_.